# What is the proper usage of scons with versioned libraries and the cache enabled?

Tags: scons

When I activate the scons cache on the following minimum working example, on linux, if I build, clean, and then build, the second build will break.  Without the cache, this example works every time.

Is this a bug, or am I using the combination of these features incorrectly?  It looks like the cache is not properly restoring the symlinks generated by the versioned shared library build properly.

```
>> scons --version      
SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
    script: v2.5.1.rel_2.5.1:3735:9dc6cee5c168[MODIFIED], 2016/11/03 14:02:02, by bdbaddog on mongodog
    engine: v2.5.1.rel_2.5.1:3735:9dc6cee5c168[MODIFIED], 2016/11/03 14:02:02, by bdbaddog on mongodog
    engine path: ['/usr/lib/scons/SCons']
Copyright (c) 2001 - 2016 The SCons Foundation

>> tree                 
.
├── bar.cpp
├── foo.cpp
└── SConstruct

0 directories, 3 files

>> cat bar.cpp
void bar() {}

>> cat foo.cpp
void foo() {}

>> cat SConstruct 
CacheDir('cache')
SharedLibrary('foo.cpp', SHLIBVERSION='1.0.0')
SharedLibrary('bar.cpp', SHLIBVERSION='1.0.0', LIBS=['foo'], LIBPATH=['.'])

>> scons --cache-debug=-
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
CacheRetrieve(bar.os):  f51aa60a1d1f47f50a872599e2d0039c not in cache
g++ -o bar.os -c -fPIC bar.cpp
CachePush(bar.os):  pushing to f51aa60a1d1f47f50a872599e2d0039c
CacheRetrieve(foo.os):  77ed043971b55f5e85a799d399e1e01a not in cache
g++ -o foo.os -c -fPIC foo.cpp
CachePush(foo.os):  pushing to 77ed043971b55f5e85a799d399e1e01a
CacheRetrieve(libfoo.so.1.0.0):  9d28d253e1e1adfb32090d08cd7cef90 not in cache
g++ -o libfoo.so.1.0.0 -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,-soname=libfoo.so.1 foo.os
Create symlinks for: 'libfoo.so.1.0.0': 'libfoo.so.1'->'libfoo.so.1.0.0', 'libfoo.so'->'libfoo.so.1.0.0'
CachePush(libfoo.so.1.0.0):  pushing to 9d28d253e1e1adfb32090d08cd7cef90
CacheRetrieve(libbar.so.1.0.0):  4cd497b57418be29d85006d10e13e5e8 not in cache
g++ -o libbar.so.1.0.0 -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,-soname=libbar.so.1 bar.os -L. -lfoo
Create symlinks for: 'libbar.so.1.0.0': 'libbar.so.1'->'libbar.so.1.0.0', 'libbar.so'->'libbar.so.1.0.0'
CachePush(libbar.so.1.0.0):  pushing to 4cd497b57418be29d85006d10e13e5e8
scons: done building targets.

>> tree
.
├── bar.cpp
├── bar.os
├── cache
│   ├── 4C
│   │   └── 4cd497b57418be29d85006d10e13e5e8
│   ├── 77
│   │   └── 77ed043971b55f5e85a799d399e1e01a
│   ├── 9D
│   │   └── 9d28d253e1e1adfb32090d08cd7cef90
│   ├── config
│   └── F5
│       └── f51aa60a1d1f47f50a872599e2d0039c
├── foo.cpp
├── foo.os
├── libbar.so -> libbar.so.1.0.0
├── libbar.so.1 -> libbar.so.1.0.0
├── libbar.so.1.0.0
├── libfoo.so -> libfoo.so.1.0.0
├── libfoo.so.1 -> libfoo.so.1.0.0
├── libfoo.so.1.0.0
└── SConstruct

5 directories, 16 files

>> scons -c
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Cleaning targets ...
Removed bar.os
Removed foo.os
Removed libfoo.so.1.0.0
Removed libfoo.so
Removed libfoo.so.1
Removed libbar.so.1.0.0
Removed libbar.so
Removed libbar.so.1
scons: done cleaning targets.

>> tree
.
├── bar.cpp
├── cache
│   ├── 4C
│   │   └── 4cd497b57418be29d85006d10e13e5e8
│   ├── 77
│   │   └── 77ed043971b55f5e85a799d399e1e01a
│   ├── 9D
│   │   └── 9d28d253e1e1adfb32090d08cd7cef90
│   ├── config
│   └── F5
│       └── f51aa60a1d1f47f50a872599e2d0039c
├── foo.cpp
└── SConstruct

5 directories, 8 files

>> scons --cache-debug=-
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
Retrieved `bar.os' from cache
CacheRetrieve(bar.os):  retrieving from f51aa60a1d1f47f50a872599e2d0039c
Retrieved `foo.os' from cache
CacheRetrieve(foo.os):  retrieving from 77ed043971b55f5e85a799d399e1e01a
Retrieved `libfoo.so.1.0.0' from cache
CacheRetrieve(libfoo.so.1.0.0):  retrieving from 9d28d253e1e1adfb32090d08cd7cef90
CacheRetrieve(libbar.so.1.0.0):  58ec677dbfc7c655a0cef296b479b485 not in cache
g++ -o libbar.so.1.0.0 -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,-soname=libbar.so.1 bar.os -L. -lfoo
/bin/ld: cannot find -lfoo
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: *** [libbar.so.1.0.0] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.

>> tree
.
├── bar.cpp
├── bar.os
├── cache
│   ├── 4C
│   │   └── 4cd497b57418be29d85006d10e13e5e8
│   ├── 77
│   │   └── 77ed043971b55f5e85a799d399e1e01a
│   ├── 9D
│   │   └── 9d28d253e1e1adfb32090d08cd7cef90
│   ├── config
│   └── F5
│       └── f51aa60a1d1f47f50a872599e2d0039c
├── foo.cpp
├── foo.os
├── libfoo.so.1.0.0
└── SConstruct

5 directories, 11 files
```

Comment: Better to send such to the users mailing list.  This looks like a bug.  I'm guessing for some reason the symlinks for the shared libraries don't get cached and therein is the source of the error.  If you look at the output for scons --tree=prune, you'll see libbar.so.1.0.0 depends on libfoo.so which depends on libfoo.so.1.0.0

Comment: I joined the list and posted a [message](https://pairlist4.pair.net/pipermail/scons-users/2017-February/005642.html), but still no help.  Did I miss something in the rules to get my question blacklisted, or does it just take time?  If it is a bug, I would like to report it, if that requires some action.  It is holding me back on a workflow I would like to use.  Thanks!

Comment: See response on users mailing list.   I think the issue is that the symlink isn't recreated after the shared library is retrieved from the cachedir.